# Function not doing do-while loop...not returning to main?

Tags: java, controls, do-while, decomposition

I have some code for my class in which we are incorporating stacks. The program reads in a list of function names and the data types that go along with them. It then allows a user to enter a function header name along with parameters. If the function name matches one of the ones read in and if the data types match then the function name and parameters are put on the stack and it prompts the user to enter a header again.

I am trying to get it to repeat the prompting with a do-while loop but it isn't executing. I'm not sure if the control isn't being transferred back to main after the data types are checked or if there is another problem. A possibly important thing to note is that the functions being called are held in a different class file than where main is located and they are incorporating functional decomposition.

```
    int x = -1;
    do {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do? Enter a number 1-3");
        System.out.println("1.) Call a Function");
        System.out.println("2.) End the Function");
        System.out.println("3.) Exit the Program");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = input.nextInt();

        switch(x) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Please enter function");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                String functionHeader = scan.nextLine();
                getName(functionHeader);
            case 2:
                System.out.println("it worked!");
            case 3:
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }while(x != 2);
```

Last function before control should be returned:

```
     public static void checkFunction(int index) {
          boolean works = true;
          if(inputParamNum != functions[index].numParams) {
              System.out.println("Number of Paramaters do not match. \nThe parameter(s) should be:");
              for(int j = 0; j < functions[index].numParams; j++) {
                  System.out.print(functions[index].params[j] + " ");
              }
              System.exit(0);
          }


          for(int i = 0; i < functions[index].numParams; i++) {
              if(functions[index].params[i].equals("String") && ! 
            (inputParams[i].substring(0,1).equals("\""))) {
                  System.out.println("You did not input a String when a String was expected. \nThe correct parameter(s) for this function are/is:");
                  for(int j = 0; j < functions[index].numParams; j++) {
                       System.out.print(functions[index].params[j] + " ");
                  }
                  System.exit(0);
              }
              else if(functions[index].params[i].equals("char") && !(inputParams[i].substring(0,1).contentEquals("\'"))) {
                  System.out.println("You did not input a char when a char was expected. \nThe correct parameter(s) for this function are/is:");
                  for(int j = 0; j < functions[index].numParams; j++) {
                      System.out.print(functions[index].params[j] + " ");
                  }
                  System.exit(0);
              }
              else if(functions[index].params[i].equals("int")) {
                  try{
                      Integer.parseInt(inputParams[i]);
                  }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                      System.out.println("You did not input an int when an int was expected. \nThe correct parameter(s) for this function are/is:");
                      for(int j = 0; j < functions[index].numParams; j++) {
                          System.out.print(functions[index].params[j] + " ");
                      }
                  }
              }
              else if(functions[index].params[i].equals("float")) {
                  try{
                      Float.parseFloat(inputParams[i]);
                  }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                      System.out.println("You did not input a float when a float was expected. \nThe correct parameter(s) for this function are/is:");
                      for(int j = 0; j < functions[index].numParams; j++) {
                          System.out.print(functions[index].params[j] + " ");
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          System.out.println("Congrats! you input correctly");
      }
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       switch(x) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Please enter function");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                String functionHeader = scan.nextLine();
                getName(functionHeader);
            case 2:
                System.out.println("it worked!");
            case 3:
                System.exit(0);
       }
```

You're missing `break` statements in your switch. You should use a good IDE such as IntelliJ Idea because it would warn you about the fall-through happening here.

```
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("it worked!");
                case 3:
                    System.exit(0);
```

Without a `break` statement, if case 2 is executed, a fall-through will happen and case 3 will also get executed.

---

### **Solution:**

You will need `break` statements as follows:

```
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Please enter function");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                String functionHeader = scan.nextLine();
                getName(functionHeader);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("it worked!");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.exit(0);
                break; //This one is technically unnecessary because it's the final case label.
```